# Remote ls output is not redirecting to file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

When I run the below code, I'getting this error

> bash: /var/out.txt: No such file or directory

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout -1    
spawn ssh user@10.103.234.1 'ls -t /var/backups/archives/' > /var/outp.log    
expect "user@10.103.234.1's password:"    
send "Password\n"    
expect eof

if [catch wait] {    
    puts "failed"    
    exit 1    
}

exit 0
```

Comment: Your requirement is not even clear. Do you want to get the command output in the local file or to a file in the target machine?

Comment: `expect -d /your/script.exp` and see what's wrong.

Comment: need command output in local file

Comment: After Password getting this when did expect -d
`
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "This system is for authorized use only.\r\nuser@10.103.234.1's password:"
send: sending "Password\n" to { exp4 }

bash: /var/outp.log: No such file or directory
expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " \r\nbash: /var/outp.log: No such file or directory\r\n"
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expect/Tcl does not understant the redirection (`>`) char. Try this:

```
spawn bash -c "ssh user@10.103.234.1 ls -t /var/backups/archives/ > /var/outp.log"
```

Comment: tried with double quoted also.. still the same error

Comment: plz post the whole output.

Comment: [root@cap-nwmon-01 user]# ./outp.sh
spawn ssh user@10.103.234.1 ls -t /var/backups/archives/ > /var/outp.log
This system is for authorized use only.
user@10.103.234.1's password:
bash: /var/outp.log: No such file or directory

Comment: what happens if u manually run `ssh user@10.103.234.1 "ls -t /var/backups/archives/ > /var/outp.log"`?

Comment: same error when manually run. but if i change the double quotes to single quote like in my original code and run it manually it works

Comment: Great.. that worked... wonderful. thank you very much.. really appreciate it :-)

Comment: may i know why u added bash -c

Comment: i dont know why `ssh user@10.103.234.1 "ls -t /var/backups/archives/ > /var/outp.log"` still fails when you manuall run it. not sure what shell you're using. use `bash -c` to make sure the cmd syntax is correct.

Comment: and `spawn ssh user@10.103.234.1 'ls -t /var/backups/archives/' > /var/outp.log` is not supposed to work but either it should not report the error `bash: /var/out.txt: No such file or directory`.

Comment: did u *litterally* copy-n-paste the error message from your terminal output?

Answer (score 0):

use tee replaced
spawn ssh user@10.103.234.1 'ls -t /var/backups/archives/|tee -a /var/outp.log'